# NodeJs Async.waterfall within Node-Webkit

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, node-webkit, node-async

I'm trying to use the nodejs async module (waterfall method) within a node-webkit app, however it does not run properly. It seems to jump straight to the last item in the chain and ignore everything else. My code works perfectly in nodejs though. I thought it could be my code, but even the following example from the async docs does the same.

```
 async.waterfall([
    function(callback){
        callback(null, 'one', 'two');
    },
    function(arg1, arg2, callback){
        callback(null, 'three');
    },
    function(arg1, callback){
        // arg1 now equals 'three'
        callback(null, 'done');
    }
], function (err, result) {
    console.log(result)
    // result now equals 'done'
});
```

However the following example that uses the async.series methods does work:

```
async.series([
function(callback){
    // do some stuff ...
    callback(null, 'one');
},
function(callback){
    // do some more stuff ...
    callback(null, 'two');
}
],
// optional callback
function(err, results){
// results is now equal to ['one', 'two']
});
```

Comment: I ran your code in node-webkit and Node.js, but the results are the same 'undefined'.

Comment: Hmm - Strange if I run it in Node.js it returns 'Done' in Node-Webkit it returns 'undefined' for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug with the async module, and there's an open issue on Github about this ([issue #302](https://github.com/caolan/async/issues/302).) The trouble is when node creates a new environment (using the vm module), the array checks async uses internally are invalid.

I fixed this by changing the Array check on line 472 in `lib/async.js` from:

```
async.waterfall = function (tasks, callback) {
    callback = callback || function () {};
    if (tasks.constructor !== Array) {
```

to:

```
async.waterfall = function (tasks, callback) {
    callback = callback || function () {};
    if (!Array.isArray(tasks)) {
```

There are a few pull requests open to fix this issue, so hopefully this will be fixed soon.

Comment: Thanks for this - I ended up putting all of the code that used the async lib into a separate file and then 'required' it. This seemed to do the trick although, I'll try your suggestion and the new nwglobal module - https://github.com/Mithgol/nwglobal